# How to follow users who sign in with twitter on my website?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
require("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");  
session_start();
//Site Account
$siteauth = new TwitterOAuth('{Consumer key}', '{Consumer secret}', '{Access token}', '{Access token secret}');
$access_token = $siteauth->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']);
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
$site_info = $siteauth->get('account/verify_credentials');

var_dump($site_info);
```

I'm trying to create a $twitteroauth object in order to use the next code:

```
$follows_faelazo = $siteauth->get('friendships/exists', 'MY-VISTOTR-ACCOUNT', 'user_b' => 'MY-SITE_ACCOUNT'));
if(!$follows_faelazo){
    echo 'You are NOT following @faelazo!';
    $siteauth->post('friendships/create', array('screen_name' => 'MY-VISTOR'));
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to follow users who log in to my site using twitter, any idea what's wrong? I'm kind of new with the twitter API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please go to [twitter dev](https://dev.twitter.com/) - > My app - > Your App -> settings -> Application type set to  Read, Write and Access direct messages.

First you are checking if you have already followed the person. to do this 2 parameters are required ,.

```
 // uname
 1.) USER_FOLLOWING
 2.) USER_FOLLOWED
```

Now the 2nd call will be to follow method so you could follow, for this 1 param is req.

```
//this can be uid/uname
1.) USER_T0_BE_FOLLOWED
```

For above mentioned please make sure you are calling methods with appropriate param.

e.g.) in the first you need to pass 4 param, client_id, client_secret , outhid, outhsecret

initially before this user needs to authenticate the app.

everything else lloks fine hope you passing proper param thats just one concern.

Comment: $follows_faelazo = $siteauth->get('friendships/exists', array('user_a' => $site_twitter, 'user_b' => $user_twitter));
if(!$follows_faelazo){
    $siteauth->post('friendships/create', array('screen_name' => $user_twitter));
 echo $user_twitter;
}
Here's the code after the authentication, Not working yet

Comment: urmmm did you cross check by outputting the response you are getting in response URI? if yes. btw r you storing all the session variables whilst authenticating cuz prolly API uses 'em internally. Im not sure though.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: Read-only application cannot POST

Comment: Oh gotcha. please sign-in to twitter developers from the account you have your app registered. Now from the top upper right corner nav. go to your apps and open your app. thereafter in the settings tab at the bottom there will be permission level defined by heading APPLICATION TYPE.

Comment: I did that :) it's Read and Write .. however at the details page at the bottom of my access token details, I get Read-only for the level.

Comment: Please update it from the bottom of settings tab. do it twice or thrice unless you don't get the twitter confirmation. sometimes twitter lags. thereafter crosscheck it on the details.